# Old Access Files and PYODBC

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, ms-access, pyodbc, 32-bit

I have a lot of old Access files (*.mdb) that were created in some version of Access prior to 2010. I cannot open them with Access 2019 or the 64 bit drivers in OBDC Data Sources x64 that are commonly referenced in PYODBC questions and answers on Stack Overflow.

The question is, "What do you do when you received the following error when trying to open up an Access file with PYODBC with the standard `{Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}` driver?"

Error message:

> [ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Cannot open a database created with a previous version of your application. (-1019)")

If you try to open up an old Access datafile using Access 2019 you will receive a very similar message.

Answer (score 2):

**Introduction**

There are several steps to solving this issue.

1. Check to see if you have 32 bit drivers for Access installed
   If not, install them from Microsoft using the Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255)
2. Set up a virtual environment with 32 bit Python
3. Select the right drivers

**1. Checking 32 bit drivers**

Search for ODBC in your Windows search bar and open the 32 bit version. If you have `Driver do Microsoft Access (*.mdb)` then you are done with this step.
[image: ODBC 32 Bit Drivers]

If you don't see this driver, you need to download the drivers from Microsoft using the link above.

**2. Setting up 32 Bit Python**
This assumes you already have Anaconda installed. You need to create a 32 bit Python virtual environment with the libraries you need to perform your work. Here is what I did to use PYODBC and Pandas with old access files.
Reference: https://titanwolf.org/Network/Articles/Article?AID=25933ee7-9343-4045-ab83-74ebae601b92

```
$ set CONDA_SUBDIR=win-32

$ conda create -n py36_32bit python=3.6.5 pandas PYODBC openpyxl spyder

$ conda activate py36_32bit

$ python

Python 3.6.8 |Anaconda, Inc.| 

(default, Feb 21 2019, 18:28:22) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
```

**3. Select the right driver**
Open up the Spyder in your new 32 bit environment and start coding. Here is an example of how to connect with your old database file.

```
    path_to_access = r"full\path\to\file.mdb"
    ###Create the connection string with the 32 bit driver
    connStr = (r"Driver={Driver do Microsoft Access (*.mdb)};"
    r"DBQ="+path_to_access+";")
    ### Connect to the database
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect(connStr)
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()
    ### Print out the table names in the database.
    for table_info in cursor.tables(tableType='TABLE'):
         print(f'Table: {table_info.table_name}')
    ### Close the connection to the file. 
    cursor.close()
    cnxn.close()
```

For additional references, I highly recommend this page on interfacing with old access files. Pandas also has a good tool for reading Access databases using `pandas.read_sql()`.

Old Access Files Reference:
https://www.barenakedcoder.com/blog/2020/04/python-and-microsoft-access-files/